# Kurt Gödel: a biography

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details, book-recommendation, logicians, goedel

I'm looking for a well-written biographical book about Kurt Gödel. Any titles you'd recommend?

Comment: [Budiansky, Journey to the Edge of Reason](https://www.amazon.com/Journey-Edge-Reason-Life-G%C3%B6del/dp/1324005440), personal biography; [Dawson, Logical Dilemmas](https://plus.maths.org/content/logical-dilemmas), academic biography; [Hao Wang, Reflections on Kurt Gödel](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Reflections_on_Kurt_G%C3%B6del/wLLePwhDOMYC?hl=en&gbpv=0), first hand account written by his personal friend.

Comment: @Conifold, thank you very much for your reply. I'm going to read the second and the third ones, waiting for the first one to be published.

Comment: Rebecca Goldstein, [Incompleteness: The Proof and Paradox of Kurt Gödel (2005)](https://books.google.it/books?id=tXk2AAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover). Jim Holt, [When Einstein Walked with Gödel Excursions to the Edge of Thought (2018)](https://books.google.it/books?id=7hE7DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover). P.Yourgrau, [A World Without Time: The Forgotten Legacy of Godel and Einstein (2005)](https://books.google.it/books?id=WJQ5DgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Grazie, @MauroALLEGRANZA!